# how do i download google data studio report as PDF

Tags: javascript, looker-studio

I have been working on to embed google data studio reports in Web application using iframe. it is working , we can see the report in iframe.

how do i download embedded google data studio report as PDF by click of a button .

Here is a sample report available in google data studio

https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/0B5FF6JBKbNJxOWItcWo2SVVVeGc/page/DjD

if you see header section , there is an option to download the report . i am looking for similar functionality in my web application. where users should be able to download the embedded google data studio report. i have looked around in google data studio website and not able to find any solution for this.

Any pointers on this would be really helpful. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score -3):

You can download it with the following button:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your answer so that they follow the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer otherwise you risk being downvoted.